# Check-in SQL database structure to the repository

Tags: sql, database, repository

What do you suggest as good ways to import database structure and commit database structure changes to the repository? Our current procedure is to export the structure into a text file then replace it the the existing text file in the repository. I find it tedious and time-consuming. Are there any utilities to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903/database-changes-versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). It is a open source Database Change Management library.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken to just doing all my structural updates as SQL scripts, so I don't have to export anything. That works out pretty good.

Comment: What I don't like about this approach is that the scripts should be kept in order or it may ruin the structure of the database.